# Dismiss DialogFragment onClick not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have an dialogfragment and its view consists of a simple seekbar and positive and negative buttons. When I dismiss dialogfragment onclick, a new dialogfragment is created and showed. After second click on button, dialog is dismissed, but my desire is dismissing after first click. Also I should note that my activity hosts two fragments and I call dialog.show() from first fragment.

MyListFragment.java

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
fndSrchFragment dialog = new fndSrchFragment();
dialog.setTargetFragment(MyListFragment.this, REQUEST_COLOR);
dialog.show(manager, SRCH_FND);
```

fndSrchFragment.java

```
public class fndSrchFragment  extends DialogFragment {
.
.
//variable definition
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.color_picker, null);
rSb=(SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.r_seek_bar);
.
.
//code for interacting with seekbar
.
.
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            int ccolor = android.graphics.Color.rgb(rComponent, gComponent, bComponent);
            sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, ccolor);
            // two click is needed for dismiss which I don't know why?
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // two click is needed for dismiss which I don't know why?
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: I also faced sometimes problems with this, don´t know why....what happens if you use dialog.dismiss(); ?

Comment: Thank you @Opiatefuchs. It has not any effect (using dialog.dismiss()).

Comment: `return builder.create()`...are you creating the dialog inside a method?You haven´t posted that...

Comment: Sounds like the problem isn't the dismissing. If it's being relaunched, that means your launching code is getting called twice. Is it in a Fragment lifecycle method or triggered by user action? Include the dialog.show()'s code context please.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs: I have called `dialog.show()` inside `onMenuItemActionExpand()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a log command inside your `onMenuItemActionExpand()`. I bet you'll see this method is called right after you dismissed the dialog. Most likely, this method is being called by the system once focus is returned from the dialog to the activity. You should but your call to `dialog.show()` inside a something like `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` instead.

Comment: Thank you @JCricket . It is probably the origion of problem. I will test log output.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering why dismiss didnt work. Problem was that the method was called twice.